# SVN Connector: IntelliJ alternative?

Tags: eclipse, svn, intellij-idea

Part of my test setup involves installing SVNConnector, which i understand is for Eclipse. Does IntelliJ have an equivalent? I've googled but can't find anything specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to install a special connector in IntelliJ IDEA. It has built-in SVN support and can also use `svn.exe` command-line client as an alternative.

Follow these steps to open SVN settings in the IDE:

1. Start IntelliJ IDEA.
2. Navigate to **File | Settings | Version Control | Subversion**.

Read the documentation:

- [Using Subversion Integration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-subversion-integration.html)

Comment: You actually need to install a command line client for SVN 1.8 or higher.